# Incorrect writing in custom allocator

Tags: rust

To track the memory allocated in my process I want to use a custom allocator, like:

```rust
#![feature(allocator_api)]

use std::alloc::{Layout, System};
use std::io::Write;
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering},
    Mutex,
};

static ALLOC_COUNTER: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);
static DEALLOC_COUNTER: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);

struct TrackingAllocator<W: Write>(MaybeUninit<Mutex<W>>);

unsafe impl<W: Write> std::alloc::GlobalAlloc for TrackingAllocator<W> {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        let mut guard = self.0.assume_init_ref().lock().unwrap();
        writeln!(guard, "alloc: {layout:?}").unwrap();
        ALLOC_COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        std::alloc::System.alloc(layout)
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
        let mut guard = self.0.assume_init_ref().lock().unwrap();
        writeln!(guard, "dealloc: {ptr:?} {layout:?}").unwrap();
        DEALLOC_COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        std::alloc::System.dealloc(ptr, layout)
    }
}

static SYSTEM: System = System;

// We use the raw system allocator for the buffer we use to track all other allocations.
#[global_allocator]
static mut GLOBAL: TrackingAllocator<Vec<u8, System>> = TrackingAllocator(MaybeUninit::uninit());

fn main() {
    // Set write target in allocator.
    unsafe {
        GLOBAL
            .0
            .write(Mutex::new(Vec::<u8, System>::new_in(SYSTEM)));
    }

    // Allocate some arbitrary data.
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _y = x
        .into_iter()
        .map(Vec::<u8>::with_capacity)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    unsafe {
        GLOBAL.0.assume_init_ref().lock().unwrap().flush().unwrap();

        let guard = GLOBAL.0.assume_init_ref().lock().unwrap().clone();
        // println!("{:?}", guard);
        let s = std::str::from_utf8(&guard).unwrap();
        println!("{s}");
        println!(
            "{} | {}",
            ALLOC_COUNTER.load(Ordering::SeqCst),
            DEALLOC_COUNTER.load(Ordering::SeqCst)
        );

        GLOBAL.0.assume_init_drop();
    }
}
```

but when running this I get:

```
   Compiling test-tracing-allocator v0.1.0 (/home/ec2-user/testing-tracing-allocator)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.22s
     Running `target/debug/test-tracing-allocator`
alloc: Layout { size: 24, align: 8 (1 << 3) }
alloc: Layout { size: 72, align: 8 (1 << 3) }
alloc: Layout { size: 1, align: 1 (1 << 0) }
alloc: Layout { size: 2, align: 1 (1 << 0) }
alloc: Layout { size: 3, align: 1 (1 << 0) }
dealloc: 0x55e1c23bac10 Layout { size: 24, align: 8 (1 << 3) }

8 | 1
```

The atomics show there should be 8 allocations and 1 deallocations, but the output only has 5 allocations.

Comment: A more [simplified example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45e791d5d2f0e03c0aee992eece1400e) indicates that some allocations happen before `main()` (running on the playground indicates 2 but it may be platform dependent), meaning your `.assume_init_ref()` in those cases is doing who knows what but funny that it doesn't outright crash.

Comment: Why don't you use `Option` instead of `MaybeUninit`?

Comment: Note that you don't need `#![feature(allocator_api)]`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman they are using `Vec<u8, System>` and `::new_in`, which require the feature

Comment: @ChayimFriedman [Why](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca19c2fa12863def54cfee83e9cba35c) use either of `Option` and `MaybeUninit`? Both `Vec` and `Mutex` have const constructors.

Comment: @kmdreko The playground link isn't working, but I think you're right correcting for this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3e920594188be35477935bff454e13da produces more accurate but still not perfect behaviour. It now captures 7 out of the 8 allocations. I'm guessing the last allocation occurs after the cloning.